# Interfaced object being dumped from memory

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

We have a funny one.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  ITestInterface = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{4059D1CD-A342-48EE-B796-84B8B5589AED}']
    function GetPort: string;
    function GetRoot: string;
  end;

  TTestInterface = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterface)
  private
    FPort: string;
    FRoot: string;
  public
    constructor Create(FileName: TFileName);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function GetPort: string;
    function GetRoot: string;
  end;

{ TTestInterface }

constructor TTestInterface.Create(FileName: TFileName);
begin
  FPort := '8080';
  FRoot := 'top';
end;

destructor TTestInterface.Destroy;
begin
  // ^ Place Breakpoint here
  inherited;
end;

function TTestInterface.GetPort: string;
begin
  Result := FPort;
end;

function TTestInterface.GetRoot: string;
begin
  Result := FRoot;
end;

type
  TTestService = class
  protected
    FTest : TTestInterface;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Process;
  end;

{ TTestService }

constructor TTestService.Create;
begin
  FTest := TTestInterface.Create('');
  (FTest as IInterface)._AddRef;
end;

destructor TTestService.Destroy;
begin
  FTest.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTestService.Process;
begin
  writeln( 'Config Root: ', FTest.GetRoot );
  writeln( 'Config Port: ', FTest.GetPort );
end;

var
  TS : TTestService;
begin
  TS := TTestService.Create;
  try
    TS.Process;
  finally
    TS.Free;
  end;
end.
```

When this application finishes it generates an Invalid Pointer Operation. 
The really strange part is that setting a break point on the destructor, you can see that it generates the error the first time it gets called, which rules out it being freed twice. It is almost as if the object is dumped from memory without calling the destructor at all.

By removing the `_AddRef` everything works as expected.

We managed to produce this on Delphi 6. Can anyone confirm this behavior on any other version?

Comment: Your code is buggy, you cannot mix interface and object references, use FTest : ITestInterface; and remove _AddRef and FTest.Free code.

Comment: In this case we need to have access to both. The object in question's interface gets hooked to a list later. We need to force the _AddRef to prevent the reference counting from disposing the class too soon.

Comment: Your code is totally broken. You'll need to fix it. The first step to redemption is for you to recognise that your code is broken, and your understanding of the mechanisms incomplete. Once you can accept that, you can make progress.

Comment: Simply stopping at the line it raises the exception would have shown you what is wrong - hint: `TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction`

Comment: @WillovanderMerwe: "*The object in question's interface gets hooked to a list later. We need to force the _AddRef to prevent the reference counting from disposing the class too soon.*" - make sure to use an interface list instead of an object list, and that would not happen.

Comment: The context of this question is use of interface in a [SOA / Dependency Injection service](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4086). So it is not an option to get rid of interface reference counting, since the class is eventually to be used outside the context of `TTestService`, in a regular Injection system, or a remote call. Question is about how to cleanly use interfaces, but still have a way to access to the implementation class, in Dephi 6 (where `as` transtyping is not available).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two variables: one for the class, and one for the interface.

- Use the interface variable to manage the instance lifetime. Don't call free, but set the interface variable to nil (or out of scope) to let the instance running.
- Use the class variable to have direct raw access to the instance, if needed - but it shouldn't be the case, or at least let the class be accessible only from protected/private members of the owner class.

So your code becomes:

```
type
  TTestService = class
  protected
    FTest: ITestInterface;
    FTestInstance : TTestInterface;
  public
    constructor Create;

    procedure Process;
  end;

{ TTestService }

constructor TTestService.Create;
begin
  FTestInstance := TTestInterface.Create('');
  FTest := FTestInstance;
end;

procedure TTestService.Process;
begin
  writeln( 'Config Root: ', FTest.GetRoot );
  writeln( 'Config Port: ', FTest.GetPort );
end;

var
  TS : TTestService;
begin
  TS := TTestService.Create;
  try
    TS.Process;
  finally
    TS.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd disable lifetime management by reference counting, and save all the bother

Comment: AFAIK it is used in the context of SOA/Injection/DependencyInversion - see [this forum entry](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4086) - so here interface is needed.

Comment: This is more a work-around, avoiding the problem. `TSingletonImplementation` as base-class instead of `TInterfacedObject` will disable reference-counting, like David said.

Comment: @Nil Not, it is not a work-around, it is the clean way of using interfaces, and still maintaining a pointer reference to the implementing class. Inheriting the class from another base class is no option in the SOA/DI context of this question. And it will work even on ARC, or with FPC.

Comment: Arnaud, good catch on finding the context the question is missing, this should be added! And you might want to mention it in your answer. This question looked to be more generic design problem or misconception about interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudBouchez. I am still curious as to why Delphi is exhibiting this behaviour. It's quite scary that it never called the destructor at all.

Comment: @Willo van der Merwe, the additional reference is raising an error in `TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction`, J... pointed that out in his answer. In Delphi XE7 a breakpoint placed on the `begin` of `destructor TTestInterface.Destroy` is reached even if the error in `BeforeDestruction` prevents any code execution in the destructor.

Comment: @Nil Thanks to @Stefan Glienke's advice and `@J...`'s answer we saw that `TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction` raises the very intuitive _Invalid Pointer Operation_ when the `RefCount <> 0`, which caused most of the confusion. Had that error been something a bit more descriptive, all of this could have been avoided.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are manually freeing an interfaced object that has a reference count greater than zero.  The exception is raised here :

```
procedure TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if RefCount <> 0 then   {!! RefCount is still 1 - you made it that way!}
    Error(reInvalidPtr);
end;
```

So... you *could* just call `(FTest as IInterface)._Release;` in the destructor in place of `FTest.Free`, but this feels like fixing one mistake by making another.  Either you want reference counting or you don't - if you do, then you should work with the object in that way (using interface variables and letting scope and variable lifetime manage the object lifetime).  If you don't want reference counting then disable it.  Either way you should pick a lifetime management model and work with it in the normal way.

---

**Case 1 : Disable Reference Counting**

If you want to disable automatic reference counting and you're using Delphi 2009 or higher you can simply do this by inheriting from [`TSingletonImplementation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Defaults.TSingletonImplementation) instead of `TInterfacedObject` :

```
TTestInterface = class(TSingletonImplementation, ITestInterface)
  private
    FPort: string;
    FRoot: string;
  public
    constructor Create(FileName: TFileName);
    destructor Destroy; override;    
    function GetPort: string;
    function GetRoot: string;
end;
```

Otherwise, you can implement this yourself by adding the required methods :

```
TTestInterface = class(TObject, ITestInterface)
  private
    FPort: string;
    FRoot: string;
  { **   Add interface handling methods ** }
  protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  { **  ----------------------   ** }
  public
    constructor Create(FileName: TFileName);
    destructor Destroy; override;    
    function GetPort: string;
    function GetRoot: string;
end;
```

which you implement as :

```
function TTestInterface.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TTestInterface._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function TTestInterface._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;
```

---

**Case 2 : Use Interface References Normally**

If you absolutely need reference counting and you still need to access the concrete class members then the simplest solution is to strictly use interface variables, let your container class pin the object lifetime, and cast to the concrete type when needed.  Lets introduce some state to the class :

```
TTestInterface = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterface)
  private
    FPort: string;
    FRoot: string;
  public
    Foo : integer;  { not an interface member...}
    constructor Create(FileName: TFileName);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function GetPort: string;
    function GetRoot: string;
end;
```

Your container class then becomes :

```
type
  TTestService = class
  protected
    FTest : ITestInterface;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Process;
  end;

{ TTestService }

constructor TTestService.Create;
begin
  FTest := TTestInterface.Create('');
end;

procedure TTestService.Process;
begin
  writeln( 'Config Root: ', FTest.GetRoot );
  writeln( 'Config Port: ', FTest.GetPort );
  WriteLn( 'Foo : ', TTestInterface(FTest).Foo);  {Cast to access class members}
end;
```

Note that the above cast of `TTestInterface(FTest)` only works in Delphi 2010 and higher.  For versions older than this you must keep a separate object reference as in @ArnaudBouchez's answer.  In either case, the point is to use interface references in the normal way to manage the object lifetime and to not rely on hacking the reference count manually.

Comment: I like the way you're thinking, but if that was the case the debugger would have stopped on the call to destructor, which it doesn't.

Comment: Your code will work only on Windows. Inheriting the class from another base class, and disabling reference counting, is no option in [the SOA/DI context of this question](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4086). The class should properly handle interface reference counting for its live time management, because it could be used in another context (e.g. remotely via SOA, or resolved at runtime using DI).

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez OP made no mention of this requirement in their question.  Since they are using D7 they are naturally only using this on Windows.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez That said, I have broadened the answer to address all possible use cases.

Comment: Your TTestService is leaking memory, for sure. The TTestInterface instance is never released. You made the problem worse, I'm afraid. And `TTestInterface(FTest)` doesn't work IIRC: you need to write `FTest as TTestInterface`,  which does not work with Delphi 7 - for old versions of Delphi, you need something like [we proposed here](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/06/13/Retrieve-the-object-instance-from-an-interface).

Comment: Excellent answer and good explanation of why this occurs - thanks @J...

Comment: @J... You call `TTestInterface.Create` so you allocated one instance, but it is never freed since the reference counting is disabled by your overridden methods. `TTestInterface(FTest)` does compile under D7, but it is a direct typecast of the interface pointer to the class, so it calls `TTestInterface` with a wrong pointer, and fails (with a GPF most of the cases).